# Decimal format conversion from one locale to another locale(en_US) in java

Tags: java, locale

I have a decimal in a string format in a locale that is not 'en_US'. I would like to convert it to a decimal in 'en_US' locale.

Eg: "123.345.123,45" -> "123345123.45" or "123,345,123.45"

"123 345,45"  -> "123345.45" or "123,345.45"

"123.345"   -> "123345" or "123,345"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like NumberFormat will do what you're looking for.

Found this snippet in the oracle documentation:

```
static public void displayNumber(Locale currentLocale) {

Integer quantity = new Integer(123456);
Double amount = new Double(345987.246);
NumberFormat numberFormatter;
String quantityOut;
String amountOut;

numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(currentLocale);
quantityOut = numberFormatter.format(quantity);
amountOut = numberFormatter.format(amount);
System.out.println(quantityOut + "   " + currentLocale.toString());
System.out.println(amountOut + "   " + currentLocale.toString());
}
```

This example prints the following; it shows how the format of the same number varies with Locale:

> 123 456   fr_FR
>
> 345 987,246   fr_FR
>
> 123.456   de_DE
>
> 345.987,246   de_DE
>
> 123,456   en_US 3
>
> 45,987.246   en_US

Here's the link that content is from:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html

---

In order to convert a formatted number string from one Locale to another, you must know the Locale from which the string was generated.  From there you can use NumberFormat.parse to convert the string back to a Number.  Then use the target Locale to create another NumberFormat and use the .format method to change the string  representation.

```
static public String displayNumber(String startValue, Locale startLocale, Locale endLocale) throws ParseException {
    NumberFormat parser = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(startLocale);
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(endLocale);
    
    Number rawNumber = parser.parse(startValue);
    
    return formatter.format(rawNumber);
}
```

Comment: I had seen this earlier but the problem i ran into is that my input had been a string "123.345,67" which is not in the en_US locale and  so i needed a way to first convert the string to a valid double in that specific locale. Thats where i was stuck.

Comment: Updated response to show how NumberFormat can serve this purpose.  If you don't know the original Locale of the String this will not work.

Comment: Thank you @Jeremiah, that was what i was looking for.. now i can use it however i want to ... Thank again

Comment: `NumberFormat parser = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("de_DE"));
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en_US"));
        Number rawNumber = parser.parse("1.234.567,89");`

 formatter.format(rawNumber); ----> gives 1.234

but if i use **Locale.Germany** in place of de_DE the answer is 1,234,567.89 

Why is the ans different when **Local.Germany** is same as **de_DE** locale

Comment: Locale.Germany specifies the language "de" with no country code.  using the country code DE changes the interpretation.  Basically, Locale.Germany is the same as Locale("de"), which appears to be different than the language & country code "de_DE".  Check the source for java.util.Locale

Comment: When i checked source i found that 

`/** Useful constant for country.*/
    static public final Locale GERMANY = createConstant("de", "DE");`

 
`/** Useful constant for language. */
    static public final Locale GERMAN = createConstant("de", "");`
 

Am i mistakenly seeing in the wrong source ?